# Transit visa at LHR for Indian citizen with USA visa

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, transit-visas, lhr, h1b-visas

I am an Indian Citizen, with a valid H1B visa and I am traveling to Europe for my vacation. I will be getting a Schengen Visa from the consulate of my destination. I wanted to ask if I have a stop at LHR (or any airport in UK for that matter), will I need a transit visa?

The layover will be on the same calendar day (about 10 hours or less), and I do not want to get out of the airport.

I did check online resources like:

- https://www.quora.com/I-am-flying-to-India-from-NYC-via-London-I-am-on-H1B-visa-Do-I-need-UK-visa#
- https://www.quora.com/H-1B-Visa-Am-I-allowed-to-travel-via-London-Heathrow-to-India-Indian-citizen-living-in-USA
  And it says that I will not require it.

I checked at this link: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa
And it says I do need it:

> You’ll need a visa to pass through the UK in transit (unless you’re exempt)
>
> You should apply for a Direct Airside Transit visa if you arrive in the UK on a flight and leave again without passing through immigration control.
>   Exemptions
>
> You don’t need a visa if you have one of the following:
>
> - a visa for Canada, New Zealand, Australia or the USA (this can be used for travel to any country)
> - a residence permit issued by Australia or New Zealand
> - a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland
> - a resident permit issued by Canada after 28 June 2002
> - a uniform format category D visa for entry into a country in the European Economic Area (EEA) or Switzerland
> - an Irish biometric visa (marked ‘BC’ or ‘BC BIVS’ in the ‘Remarks’ section)
> - a Schengen Approved Destination Scheme (ADS) group tourism visa where the holder is travelling to the Schengen country that issued the visa
> - a flight ticket from the Schengen area, if you can prove that you entered the Schengen area in the previous 30 days on the basis of a valid Schengen ADS visa
> - a valid USA I-551 Temporary Immigrant visa issued by the USA (a wet-ink stamp version will not be accepted)
> - a valid USA permanent residence card issued by the USA on or after 21 April 1998
> - an expired USA I-551 Permanent Residence card issued by the USA on or after 21 April 1998, with a valid I-797 letter authorising extension
> - a valid standalone US Immigration Form 155A/155B issued by the USA (attached to a sealed brown envelope)

I don't see any exemption criteria that qualifies a H1B Visa holder with a valid Schengen visa to transit without a transit-visa.

In case I do need it, how long does it usually take? I have about 30 days before I travel.

**Note:** Last year I had a stop in Toronto, and I found that I need a transit visa the hard way. The airline didn't warn me until I tried to check-in into the flight the day before, and as a result I had to do a last minute change which was very expensive. So this time I want to confirm/assure to avoid the last minute stress.

Comment: You don’t see the very first exemption in the list?  The one that says that says you don’t need a UK transit visa if you have a visa for Canada, New Zealand, Australia or the *USA*, and that if you have that visa you can travel via the UK to any country, not just the country of the visa?

Comment: I literally missed the `USA` in that sentence! This visa thing really stresses me out! Thanks for pointing this out :). I think I am clear in that case!

Comment: @MichaelHampton the OP has already checked via the process included in that question and answer, but needed clarification about the results of it.  So, not necessarily a duplicate.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks, yes I already checked that link. I didn't read the results correctly and got confused. The results do say that if I have a valid US visa, then I do not need a transit visa.